# Get all properties from a view model to display in array

Tags: c#, asp.net, orchardcms, hubspot

I have a view model that have a lot of properties, and I created a custom attribute for send the data to hubspot, because hubspot need a specific nomenclature, then I need to create a method that have some king of iterator, that for every property that contain my custom attribute he put a specific output, here is the code:

```
public class CreateTrialUserHubspotViewModel {

    [HubspotAttribute("firstname")]   
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [HubspotAttribute("lastname")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [HubspotAttribute("jobtitle")]
    [Display(Name = "Job title")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Now this is my custom attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class HubspotAttribute : System.Attribute {
    public readonly string hubspotValue;

    public HubspotAttribute(string value)
    {
        this.hubspotValue = value;
    }
}
```

And then I need to create a method that take a viewmodel object and create my output, I need some suggest about how to do that, will be something like this:

```
private static RowValidation ValidateRowWithManifest<T>(CreateTrialUserHubspotViewModel trialUser) {
        RowValidation validation = new RowValidation();

        FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(T).GetPropertiesOfSomeWay;

        foreach (DataType field in fields) {
           output+=whatINeed
        }
        return validation;
    }
}
```

The needed output will be like: [firstname:"pepe", lastname="perez", jobtitle"none"]. just calling that method will return all the data I need.

Comment: Your data output doesn't even make sense.  You have colons equals signs and no representor of a key/value pair.  What is it that you actually need?

Comment: let me explain better, I have properties, that have names(of course), but I added some custom attr for have the exact name that I need for every prop, so I need, a method that expect a viewmodel object, then he build a string for every prop that be prop.customattr + ":" + viewModelObject.value. tell me if you understand better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for something that will concatenate properties into a string that ***looks*** like a JSON string (and that would be a better way to handle it), you can use something like the following:

```
private static string CreateOutput(CreateTrialUserHubspotViewModel trialUser)
{
    var properties = trialUser.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(HubspotAttribute))).ToList();

    var values = properties.Select(x =>
    {
        var att = x.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(HubspotAttribute));
        var key = ((HubspotAttribute)att).hubspotValue;
        var val = x.GetValue(trialUser);
        return $"{key}:{val}";
    });

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    values.ToList().ForEach(v =>
    {
        sb.Append(v);
        if (values.Last() != v) sb.Append(',');
    });

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: yeah, something like that, thanks. I am new with c#. I use to be a java guy, again ty.

Comment: @dayanrr91 No problem.  Like I said, your mileage may improve by looking into JSON serialization instead, but this will at least get you started on what you need :).

Answer (score 1):

```
 public string GetString<T>(T @object)
        {
            var output = new StringBuilder();
            var type = typeof(T);
            var properties = type.GetProperties();
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HubspotAttribute), true);
                if (attributes.Length == 0)
                    continue;

                var name = ((HubspotAttribute)attributes[0]).hubspotValue;
                var value = property.GetValue(@object) ?? "none";
                output.AppendFormat("{0}:\"{1}\",", name, value);
            }

            var fields = output.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
            return string.Format("[{0}]", fields);

        }
```

Comment: not generic enough, you are tied to a specific HubspotAttribute